# how to enable HTML5 Storage in Ubuntu web browser?

Tags: internet, browser

I use Ubuntu 14.04 os and also use Ubuntu web browser for open paytm.

but now I can't open this site..

the error is "please enable HTML5 storege to continue"

how to solve it??

Answer (score 0):

The page you are trying to load seems to require a technique called [Web Storage](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Web_storage).

> ...software methods and protocols used for storing data in a web
>   browser

As it is somehow unclear which page you are refering to and which browser you are using i would recommend the following:

As a first step try to load your side in either

- Firefox
- Google Chrome

Both browsers should support Web Storage out of the box.

[Here](http://html5demos.com/storage) is a demo side which tests your browser storage capabilities